# Reusing a component over multiple modules in angular

Tags: angular, module, components

Hi guys I am fairly new to the angular space and am trying to use a component that I created in AppModule in two other modules to reduce redundant code. I tried exporting the component from AppModule and import in the other modules but that did not seem to work.

Doing that gave me the errors:

```
error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AdminModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
```

```
error NG6004: Present in the NgModule.exports of AppModule but neither declared nor imported.
```

I am unable to solve the error. Can any of you give any suggestions as to how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please post a screenshot of your `AppModule`? It would be easier to debug.

Comment: You should probably use a shared module, and import into modules where you are going to use it.

Comment: Have you added the component to the 'declarations' and 'exports' in the AppModule?

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. Creating shared module and exporting the components solved my issue. Appreciate the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is the following:

1. If you have a folder with "shared" components, create a shared module for all of them. Include your components array in the `declarations` and `exports` of the shared module. Include this shared module in every component you wish to use it.
2. If you only want to use this component as "shared", just create a module for it, add it to `exports` and again include this module wherever you want to use the component.

To answer your issue, it's coming from the fact that you're not importing the `module` that's exporting your required component.

Comment: Thank you so much. Tried this and it worked. Will make sure to create shared components under a shared module from now onwards. Appreciate the help.